# Add descriptive text of table captions below table number in latex

Tags: tables, captions

I use the following to set captions of tables defined in my Overleaf document.

```
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{width=\textwidth}
\caption { \label{tab:2}\textbf{Optimal length of descriptive text is typed here}}
}
\end{table}
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to set the descriptive text of the caption below the table number caption.

Example,

```
                        TABLE II
OPTIMAL LENGTH OF THE DESCRIPTIVE TEXT IS TYPED HERE
```

Comment: Pleaase. extend your code snippet to complete small document with your table. Some document classes has default table caption style as you like to have.

Comment: @Zarko I am using the document class template available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/henriqueslab-biorxiv-template/nyprsybwffws) and this doesn't support the caption style type like how I want.

Comment: You still not provide MWE. If this "template" is for some journal, doesn't change anything in it. II is designed as they like to have formatted articles. For showed caption style look `caption` package. With it is simple to achieve desired format. For provide me an example of their use, I need to see your MWE first,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enterally clear (to me) what you like to have (since you not provide an MWE).

Two options cross my mind:

- using small caps:

```
\usepackage{caption} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\captionsetup[table]{font=sc,                      
                     labelsep=newline}
```

[image]

- using uppercase

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{upper}{#1#2\uppercase{#3}\par}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline, 
              format = upper, 
              tablename=TABLE}
```

[image]

*Note*, if you prepare article for some journal, which publisher provide own "template" (document class), don't change anything in this template. They design it by intention, that articles are formatted as they like to have.

Comment: adding `labelsep=newline` helps. But there is a problem while adding a caption that is a bit long ( e.g. `my caption with desired format my caption with desired format` ) in two-column format  of an article that title spans to the second column. I tried setting `\captionsetup[table]{font=sc, labelsep=newline, width = \textwidth}` but this didn't help

Comment: @Natasha, please consider my comments below your question. Provide MWE, as you asked. Let be with more realistic document example. Without it I can only guess what you like to have. For details about caption, please read `caption` documentation.